# Is there an app for Django to manage fields of models?

Tags: django

Like in phpmyadmin, we have an visual interface to manage fields. Can we do the same thing in Django?

Answer (score 0):

If your Django connected database is e.g. PostgreSQL, you could use `pgAdmin4` (https://www.pgadmin.org/). So it is actually not about managing the tables in Django but in a database tool (visually). To manipulate your database schema you will have to use `Models` in your Django application (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/).